# What does *G* mean in bash echo?

Tags: string, bash, replace, echo

Not too often, but frequently enough to annoy me, when I put the string `*G*` in a variable and "echo" it back, I see some file names, usually from a text file in the directory to which BASH is pointed. I thought that might be an auto-complete function, but I can't find anything on it in those areas. Could someone tell me what's happening when I echo a string with that combination of characters? I'd like to "turn it off" if I could, possibly.

Comment: `*` is 0 or more characters when globbing.

Answer (score 3):

It's a wild card, matching all files in the current directory with the character `G` in their names.

It's explained in [this section](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) of the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html).

If you really want to disable it, you can use:

```
set -f
```

or

```
set -o noglob
```

as explained [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)

But it's an amazingly useful feature, and I encourage you to leave it enabled and learn to use it.

If you want to turn it off for a single command, you can can escape any special characters with quotation marks or backslashes:

```
echo '*G*'
echo "*G*"
echo \*G\*
```

Incidentally, this feature is not specific to the `echo` command; it applies to *all* commands in the shell.  For example:

```
ls *.txt
```

gives you a directory listing of all files whose names end in `.txt`.

Comment: Keith - I don't think I'll "go in for" the noglob option. I happen to use asterisk-and-something strings with ls and other commands too often. I'll stick to the single-quote or backslash methods. **BZT**

Comment: @SilversleevesX: Just curious: if you've been using wildcards, how did you not know what `*G*` means?

Answer (score 1):

It's a wildcard file name, `*G*` simply means any number of characters (zero or more) followed by `G` followed by any number of characters.

In other words, any file name with a `G` in it. If there are *no* files with a `G` in it, `bash` simply gives you your original string, as per the following transcript:

```
pax> mkdir qqq ; cd qqq ; touch paxfile

pax> ls -al
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 pax pax 0 Apr  3 10:05 paxfile

pax> echo *x*
paxfile

pax> echo *G*
*G*
```

You can *turn it off* by simply preventing the shell from expanding the filenames:

```
pax> echo '*x*'
*x*
```

Alternatively, `bash` has a `GLOBIGNORE` variable which holds a colon-separated list of file names that you *don't* want expanded, so you could possibly use that as well, although setting it up for an arbitrary directory is rather painful (and, yes, the method below won't work well for files with embedded spaces so, before you complain, it's for demonstrative purposes only):

```
pax> GLOBIGNORE=pax

pax> echo *x*
*x*

pax> touch xyzzy twisty ; unset GLOBIGNORE ; GLOBIGNORE=$(echo *x* | tr ' ' ':')

pax> echo $GLOBIGNORE == * # only twisty should expand here (no x)
paxfile:xyzzy == twisty
```

Comment: Of course, single-quotes to get the plain text. I should have thought of that myself. Thanks to paxdiablo, Keith Thompson and alex. And thanks to Pumbaa80 for doing the edit on my OQ. BZT